# django-haystack and multithreaded uwsgi causing mutleple seach indexes

Tags: django, django-haystack, uwsgi

I"m using a single search index, and I keep getting an exception

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Model '%s' has more than one 'SearchIndex`` handling it. Please exclude either '%s' or '%s' using the 'HAYSTACK_EXCLUDED_INDEXES' setting." % (model, self.indexes[model], index))
```

This seems to be a known issue with the master branch on haystack.  However, I haven't found a solution. Does any one know how to prevent this?